# Match words in a data frame to a string in R

Tags: r, match

I have a data frame from a recall task where participants recall as many words as they can from a list they learned earlier. Here's a mock up of the data. Each row is a subject and each column (w1-w5) is a word recalled:

```
df <- data.frame(subject = 1:5,
  w1 = c("screen", "toad", "toad", "witch", "toad"), 
  w2 = c("package", "tuna", "tuna", "postage", "dinosaur"), 
  w3 = c("tuna", "postage", "toast", "athlete", "ranch"), 
  w4 = c("toad", "witch", "tuna", "package", "NA"), 
  w5 = c("windwo", "mermaid", "NA", "NA", "NA")
)
```

Which produces the following data frame:

```
  subject     w1       w2      w3      w4      w5
1       1 screen  package    tuna    toad  windwo
2       2   toad     tuna postage   witch mermaid
3       3   toad     tuna   toast    tuna      NA
4       4  witch  postage athlete package      NA
5       5   toad dinosaur   ranch      NA      NA
```

I want to match each word produced (columns w1 - w5) to a list of the correct words, which are:

```
words <- c("screen", "package", "tuna", "toad", "window", 
  "postage", "witch", "mermaid", "toast", "dinosaur")
```

I only want to award points for words that are spelled correctly and are not repeated. So for example, for the data above I'd like to end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
  subject nCorrect
1       1        4
2       2        5
3       3        3
4       4        3
5       5        2
```

Subject 1 would get four points because they misspelled one word.

Subject 2 would get five points.

Subject 3 would get 3 points because they repeated tuna and are missing one word.

Subject 4 would get three points because they have one incorrect word and one missing word.

Subject 5 would get two points because they have one incorrect word and two missing words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.frame(subject = df$subject
           , nCorrect = apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) sum(unique(x) %in% words)))

#   subject nCorrect
# 1       1        4
# 2       2        5
# 3       3        3
# 4       4        3
# 5       5        2
```

With `data.table` (same result)

```
setDT(df)

df[, sum(unique(unlist(.SD)) %in% words), by = subject]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert the data in long format. Group on `subject` to use `dplyr::summarise` to find correct number of matching answers.

```
library(tidyverse)

words <- c("screen", "package", "tuna", "toad", "window", 
           "postage", "witch", "mermaid", "toast", "dinosaur")

df %>% gather(key, value, -subject) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise(nCorrect = sum(unique(value) %in% words))
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   subject nCorrect
#    <int>    <int>
# 1       1        4
# 2       2        5
# 3       3        3
# 4       4        3
# 5       5        2
```